# NEST (ElasticSearch) matching Highlights to documents

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight, nest

I'm using C# NEST with ElasticSearch. I'm able to query an index of *Products* and look in their `Name` and `CategoryName` fields for matches. I can also extend the query using `Highlights`.

Now in my `IQueryResponse` response I have two collections: (1) `.Documents` and (2) `.Highlights`.

e.g.: Consider the search for: "cat" which has 3 document results:

```
{
   { Name: "Cat product", CategoryName: "Category1" },
   { Name: "Some product", CategoryName: "Category2" },
   { Name: "Some product2", CategoryName: "Category3" }
}
```

But now I have 4 highlight results:

```
{
   { Field: "name", Highlights: ['"<u>Cat</u> product"'] },
   { Field: "categoryName", Highlights: ['"<u>Cat</u>egory1"'] },
   { Field: "categoryName", Highlights: ['"<u>Cat</u>egory2"'] },
   { Field: "categoryName", Highlights: ['"<u>Cat</u>egory3"'] }
}
```

They seem to be in no way related to each other. **How do I know which `Highlight` item belongs to which `Document` item?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IQueryResponse` also exposes `.DocumentsWithMetaData` of type `IEnumerable<IHit<T>>` where T is the type of your document

This is basically the unwrapped view of the results as return by elasticsearch `IHit<T>` has many useful properties such as the `Highlights`.

I've added a DocumentId result to the highlight class `Highlight` so that no matter how you get to the highlight you can relate it back easily to the hit.

So use `.DocumentsWithMetaData` for now, the next release will have a more logical API for highlights.

Comment: I was already trying to iterate the `.Hits` property but that wasn't possible. Then I found the `.DocumentsWithMetaData` property which had what I needed! Thanks.

Comment: @Martijn Laarman Do you have an example of how this can be achieved with version 7.x ?  It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

here is an updated answer for version 7.x. You receive two collections as before, .Documents and .Hits . 
Within .Hits  each one has an .Id that matches the _id of the index in elasticsearch. Note: if you request more than one highlighting .NumberofFragments in your query, you will just keep overwriting the result.title and result.content in the code below, so take this as a loose example to indicate how you can match the highlight result to the correct document result, and then overwrite the document field with the one containing the highlighting.

```
if (response.Documents.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (MyResultClass result in response.Documents) //cycle through your results
    {
         foreach (var hit in response.Hits) // cycle through your hits to look for match
         {
              if (hit.Id == result.id) //you found the hit that matches your document
              {
                    foreach (var highlightField in hit.Highlight)
                    {
                           if (highlightField.Key == "title")
                           {
                                foreach (var highlight in highlightField.Value)
                                {
                                    result.title = highlight.ToString();
                                }
                           }
                           else if (highlightField.Key == "content")
                           {
                                foreach (var highlight in highlightField.Value)
                                {
                                    result.content = highlight.ToString();
                                }
                           }
                   }
             }
      }
}
```

Comment: highlight.Value does not contain the entire field value, it only appears to contain the value starting at the first hit. Setting fragmentSize = 20,000 only returned more after the first hit. Is there something else required?